# linux + running swapoff and swapon on the background

Tags: linux, bash, process, swap

We want to update the `vm.swappiness` from 10 to 1 and to perform `swapoff` and `swapon` , so the consuming of memory will be only from the memory cards and not from disk

So we wrote the following bash script  (script should be run on **195** LINUX RHEL 7.6 servers):

```
more /var/tmp/swap_conf_primary.sh
#!/bin/bash
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1
sed -i 's/vm.swappiness = 10/vm.swappiness = 1/'   /etc/sysctl.conf"
sleep 2
swapoff-a 
swapon -a 
.
.
.
```

e notice that the `swapoff` process takes a long time -  a few hours (on some machines even 5-6 hours), so we decided to perform the `swapoff` and `swapon` with & as follows:

```
$ more /var/tmp/swap_conf_primary.sh
#!/bin/bash
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1
sed -i 's/vm.swappiness = 10/vm.swappiness = 1/'   /etc/sysctl.conf"
sleep 2
/var/tmp/swap_conf_secondery.sh &
.
.
.
```

While

```
$ /var/tmp/swap_conf_secondery.sh &
#!/bin/bash
echo “`date`  swapoff -a” >/tmp/swap_proccess.log
swapoff -a 
echo “`date`  swapon -a” >/tmp/swap_proccess.log
swapon -a
```

After making the change above, we also added an additional script  `/var/tmp/swap_conf.sh`, that will run as a process, and automatically do `swapoff` and `swapon`, without depending on the “parent” script - `/var/tmp/swap_conf_primary.sh`.

We are not sure if the approach by the script   `/var/tmp/swap_conf_secondery.sh &`, is the best option that we can do. So, are there better options?

Comment: What are you trying to gain by running the commands in the background? They will still take several hours. Is this just so you can launch them quickly on the multiple servers?

Comment: the script that I shared , is part of long bash script , so all other additional bash will not performed until swapoff and swapon will finished , so this is the reason that we are thinking to set the secondary script with & , so all other bash tasks will cont

Comment: OK, and what does `/var/tmp/swap_conf_secondery.sh` (pedantic note: you probably meant *second**a**ry*) do? You haven't included it, unless it's the one you call `/var/tmp/swap_conf.sh`.

Comment: sorry for confusing , Up update the Question ( was typo )

Comment: What is the purpose of the `swapoff`/`swapon` cycle?

Comment: Consider checking if the system has enough free RAM to fit the entire swap before running `swapoff`.

Comment: yes we have enough free RAM